# Remove Stopwords in French AND English in TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, nltk, stop-words, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to remove stopwords in French and English in TfidfVectorizer. So far, I've only managed to remove stopwords from the English language. When I try to enter the French language for the stop_words, I get an error message that says it's not built-in.

**In fact, I get the following error message:**

```
ValueError: not a built-in stop list: french
```

I have a text document containing 700 lines of text mixed in French and English.

I am doing a clustering project of these 700 lines using Python. However, a problem arises with my clusters: I am getting clusters full of French stopwords, and this is messing up the efficiency of my clusters.

**My question is the following:**

Is there any way to add French stopwords or manually update the built-in English stopword list so that I can get rid of these unnecessary words?

**Here's the TfidfVectorizer code that contains my stopwords code:**

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                             min_df=0.2, stop_words='english',
                             use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, 
ngram_range=(1,3))
```

The removal of these French stopwords will allow me to have clusters that are representative of the words that are recurring in my document.

*For any doubt regarding the relevance of this question, I had asked a similar question last week. However, it is not similar as it does not use TfidfVectorizer.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This may not be relevant, but just in case, there may be unicode/utf8 characters depending on the list/file you use for the stop_words array, and you may need to change them to avoid warnings. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443802/unicode-warning-when-using-nltk-stopwords-with-tfidfvectorizer-of-scikit-learn

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use good stop words packages from [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) or [Spacy](https://spacy.io/), two super popular NLP libraries for Python. Since achultz has already added the snippet for using [stop-words](https://pypi.org/project/stop-words/) library, I will show how to go about with NLTK or Spacy.

### NLTK:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

final_stopwords_list = stopwords.words('english') + stopwords.words('french')
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8,
  max_features=200000,
  min_df=0.2,
  stop_words=final_stopwords_list,
  use_idf=True,
  tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem,
  ngram_range=(1,3))
```

NLTK will give you 334 stopwords in total.

### Spacy:

```
from spacy.lang.fr.stop_words import STOP_WORDS as fr_stop
from spacy.lang.en.stop_words import STOP_WORDS as en_stop

final_stopwords_list = list(fr_stop) + list(en_stop)
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8,
  max_features=200000,
  min_df=0.2,
  stop_words=final_stopwords_list,
  use_idf=True,
  tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem,
  ngram_range=(1,3))
```

Spacy gives you 890 stopwords in total.

Comment: PS: Spacy is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 1):

Igor Sharm noted ways to do things manually, but perhaps you could also install the [stop-words package](https://pypi.org/project/stop-words/#basic-usage). Then, the since TfidfVectorizer allows a list as a stop_words parameter,

```
from stop_words import get_stop_words

my_stop_word_list = get_stop_words('english') + get_stop_words('french')

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                             min_df=0.2, stop_words=my_stop_word_list,
                             use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem, 
ngram_range=(1,3))
```

You could also read and parse the [french.txt file in the github project](https://github.com/Alir3z4/stop-words/blob/bd8cc1434faeb3449735ed570a4a392ab5d35291/french.txt) as needed, if you want to include only some words.

Comment: Totally agree that this is also good approach, as requires less action, but imo in real life applications in every sphere of research there are some specific stop words, which are obvious when you know the topic of the research (e.g when all documents are about sports, you might enhance your search by removing words like 'sport', 'athlete',etc) and even small research on idf of your data can give valuable insight which words are most likely stopwords for you(ofc including well-known stopwords is always a good idea, but some additional can do much in improving the model ).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the easiest way to workaround this problem is to manually delete the stopwords in preprocessing stage(while taking list of most common french phrases from elsewhere).

Also, should be handy to check which stopwords are most commonly occuring in english and french in your text/model(either by just their occurencies or idf) and add them to stopwords which you exclude in preprocessing stage.

If you prefer to delete the words using tfidfvectorizer buildin methods, then consider making a list of stopwords that you want to include both french and english and pass them as

```
stopwords=[a,he,she,le,...]
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=200000,
                             min_df=0.2, stop_words=stopwords,analyzer=’word’,
                             use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_and_stem)
```

Important thing is,cite from [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html):

> ‘english’ is currently the only supported string value

So, for now you will have to manually add some list of stopwords, which you can find anywhere on web and then adjust with your topic, for example:
[stopwords](https://www.ranks.nl/stopwords/french)